# Encryption based on user entered key

Tags: java, encryption, password-protection, password-encryption

**Context:** Multi-tenant application

**Feature:** Encryption of sensitive data

**Story:**
As an admin of a tenant I want to encrypt the sensitive data using my own password or pass phrase so that I, and only I, am in full control of the key used.

**Acceptance criteria:**

1. Admin of each tenant should be able to define the password or pass phrase to be used for encryption
2. Only that tenant admin who supplied the original password or pass phrase should have knowledge of the key
3. Once the password or pass phrase has been supplied by the tenant admin, it should be stored securely

**My questions**

1. We have been so far using symmetric key encryption with application wide key hard-coded in the application. This is no longer going to work if each of the tenant want to use their own key. How can we let each user define their own key?
2. How and where to store the key?
3. Is storing the password/pass phrase in a cert a valid option? If so then how to protect the keystore?

Comment: Is a password (or pass phrase) that the application prompts for not an option?

Comment: When you say, "I and only I", do you mean that even your service never decrypts the data? That is, it just returns the encrypted block to the user and something decrypts it client-side (like some online backup services)? Or do you mean that your app still behaves as it does now, users see their data without extra effort/config on client, but behind the scenes tenant 1's data is encrypted with a different key than tenant 2?

Comment: First you say "Admin should be able to define the key" and "Only the admin should have knowledge of the key"; then "How can we let each user define their own key?". These seem to be incompatible. What am I missing?

Comment: @ckhan The system should be able to encrypt and decrypt the data based on the pass phrase entered by the user. And yes behind the scenes tenant 1's data should be encrypted with a diff key than tenant 2. But the key for each tenant should be stored securely so that it is known only to that particular tenant's admin.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Each tenant will have 1 user designated as the admin and only he should have knowledge about the key.

Comment: @MarkWilkins Yes it is the password/pass phrase that the application prompts for the tenant admin to enter. Once entered it should be accessed and understandable only to the admin and no one else (even the application team should not be able to know what that pass phrase is).

Comment: Are you trying to create a kind of PKI?

Comment: @alain.janinm Not sure...do you think PKI is the solution to this problem? If so then can you please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry I'm totally wrong if you use symmetric key encryption then you're not looking for a public key infrastructure.

Comment: @alain.janinm If PKI is the solution for this then I will use it. I just need more details on how to use PKI for this. tx,

Comment: @Pangea PKI is for asymmetric encryption (public -private keys). In your question you say you use symmetric encryption (private key). So you can't really use this infrastructure. But you can create a similar system ; an authority that create secret key based on user plateform, and an authority that verify the identity of users. For storage you can use bdd to store the user key, if you want to keep it hidden, work with an MD5 hash.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to encrypt/decrypt without knowledge of the keys. Otherwise it seems a clear cut case for PBE using key derivation function (PBKDF2).You may use asymmetric encryption, but it would only protect the private key during encryption in your use case.

Comment: +1 for PBE. Can you please elaborate on "but it would only protect the private key during encryption in your use case.".

Comment: The reason to use public / private key is in the end to be able to encrypt data without having to share the private key. If you are both the person encrypting as well as decrypting the data on the same system (at the same time) PKI does not make too much sense. It may make sense on different systems and or time frames.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet of code showing how to use password-based encryption (PBE) in your application, taken from the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#PBEEx):

```
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec;
PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec;
SecretKeyFactory keyFac;

// Salt
byte[] salt = {
    (byte)0xc7, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x8c,
    (byte)0x7e, (byte)0xc8, (byte)0xee, (byte)0x99
};

// Iteration count
int count = 20;

// Create PBE parameter set
pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count);

// Prompt user for encryption password.
// Collect user password as char array (using the
// "readPasswd" method from above), and convert
// it into a SecretKey object, using a PBE key
// factory.
System.out.print("Enter encryption password:  ");
System.out.flush();
pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(readPasswd(System.in));
keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

// Create PBE Cipher
Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");

// Initialize PBE Cipher with key and parameters
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

// Our cleartext
byte[] cleartext = "This is another example".getBytes();

// Encrypt the cleartext
byte[] ciphertext = pbeCipher.doFinal(cleartext);
```

Comment: Thx but where and how to store the password (returned by readPasswd(System.in)). Idea is to get the password from the tenant admin once and store it somewhere.

Comment: With a bit of work, you can store it in a key store. Take a look at [this](http://kingsfleet.blogspot.com/2008/12/storing-password-somewhere-safe.html) blog post. The key store in turn is protected by a password; at some point you'll have to store a (hashed) password in your system or ask the user for it

Comment: any good recommendations on better way of creating the hash and storing it

Comment: You could store it in a database, assuming that a good security policy is enforced on the database it should be safe there. If that's overkill for your application, another (less-secure) option would be to put it in a file. Anyway, at some point you need to stop and say ok, this is secure enough. Otherwise you'll have to worry about the password of the password of the password of the...

Comment: PBEWithMD5andDES is out dated. You can use the same code but with PBKDF2 (java may have it as PBKDF2 SHA1)